# Materialize CSS Tab not exhibiting scroll behaviour

Tags: javascript, html, tabs, materialize

I'm not sure why my tabs element isn't exhibiting scroll behaviour. It seems like the `li` elements in the tabs `ul` just overflow to the next row  instead, as shown [here](http://prntscr.com/npnisd).

I've initialized both materialize and the tabs correctly I think. Any suggestions as to why this is happening would be appreciated. I've tried disabling all my external CSS and JS but it doesn't seem to solve the problem.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rgmZOY) (scrolling problem not shown here, just the code is there since it's a lot)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things that I see:

- In your Codepen you have a typo: `{swipable: true}` -> `{swipeable: true}`
- You are using jQuery but in the codepen there is no jQuery included, please include this to your code
- Please check the documentation of the tabs on this page:
  https://materializecss.com/tabs.html#swipeable

As you see in the HTML they use the following markup for the UL:

```
<ul id="tabs-swipe-demo" class="tabs">
    <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test-swipe-1">Test 1</a></li>
    <li class="tab col s3"><a class="active" href="#test-swipe-2">Test 2</a></li>
    <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test-swipe-3">Test 3</a></li>
  </ul>
```

The import thing is that they use the `a href` ID to relate to the ID of the DIV element like: `#test-swipe-1`.

Div ELEMENTS:

```
  <div id="test-swipe-1" class="col s12 blue">Test 1</div>
  <div id="test-swipe-2" class="col s12 red">Test 2</div>
  <div id="test-swipe-3" class="col s12 green">Test 3</div>
```

This way Materialize knows to which DIV ID it has to show above

Comment: When i correct it to `{swipeable: true}` the indicator bar at the bottom of each tab disappears, so I guess I don't want that feature. I'm just wondering why it's not "overflowing" properly (i.e. such that I can scroll). I'd imagine there's something else messing with the materialize javascript, but the only libraries I'm using is jquery and materialize.